# Manter background em DrawingView

Tags: java, android, background, drawing

Estou precisando que um aplicativo efetue desenho sobre um plano de fundo específico, o código está funcionando tudo certinho, porém quando eu vou apagar/corrigir uma linha errada, ele apaga o plano de fundo sendo que o background deve se manter. Porém, ele está apagando a imagem de fundo junto (as linhas).

> IMAGEM INICIAL (Antes do Desenho)

[image: Imagem inicial, antes de iniciar o desenho]

> IMAGEM COM ALGO DESENHADO

[image: Imagem com um desenho já iniciado]

> APÓS EFETUAR UMA CORREÇÃO NO DESENHO

[image: Imagem após efetuar uma correção no desenho]

> Código da DrawingView

```
public class DrawingView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Canvas m_Canvas;

    private Path m_Path;

    private Paint m_Paint;

    private ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> paths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();

    private ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();

    private float mX, mY;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private boolean isEraserActive = false;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        setFocusable(true);

        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        //setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        //setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        onCanvasInitialization();
    }

    public void onCanvasInitialization() {

        m_Paint = new Paint();

        m_Paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        m_Paint.setDither(true);
        m_Paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        m_Paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        m_Paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        m_Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(3);


        m_Canvas = new Canvas();
        m_Path = new Path();
        Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint);
        paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Pair<Path, Paint> p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
        }
    }

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

        if (isEraserActive) {

            //m_Paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            m_Paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            //m_Paint.reset();
            m_Paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            m_Paint.clearShadowLayer();

            m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
            paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));

        } else {
            m_Paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            m_Paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
            paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));

        }


        m_Path.reset();
        m_Path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            m_Path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        m_Path.lineTo(mX, mY);

        // commit the path to our offscreen
        m_Canvas.drawPath(m_Path, m_Paint);

        // kill this so we don't double draw
        m_Path = new Path();
        Paint newPaint = new Paint(m_Paint); // Clones the mPaint object
        paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(m_Path, newPaint));
    }

    public void activateEraser()
    {
        m_Paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        isEraserActive = true;
    }


    public void deactivateEraser()
    {
        isEraserActive = false;
    }

    public boolean isEraserActive()
    {
        return isEraserActive;
    }


    public void reset()
    {
        paths.clear();

        invalidate();
    }

}
```

**Observação: Já tentei usar o `Color.TRANSPARENT`, porém não funciona.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em vez de desenhar as *paths* directamente no *Canvas* da *View* use um outro *Canvas* associado a um *Bitmap* e desenhe nele.

No `onDraw()` desenhe esse *Bitmap* no canvas da *View*.

Declare dois novos atributos na classe *DrawingView*:

```
public class DrawingView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    //Bitmap e Canvas usados para desenhar.
    private Bitmap strokes;
    private Canvas strokeCanvas;

    private Canvas m_Canvas;
    ........
    ........
    ........
}
```

Crie-os no método `onSizeChanged()`

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    //Cria o Bitmap e o Canvas onde o desenho será feito
    if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
        strokes = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        strokeCanvas = new Canvas(strokes);
    }

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}
```

Altere o método `onDraw` de forma as *paths* serem desenhadas nesse *Canvas* e que desenhe o *Bitmap* no *Canvas* da *View*:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    for (Pair<Path, Paint> p : paths) {
        //As paths são desenhadas no strokeCanvas
        strokeCanvas.drawPath(p.first, p.second);
    }

    //O Bitmap que tem o desenho é desenhado no canvas da view.
    canvas.drawBitmap(strokes,0,0,null);
}
```

Para testes usei este layout:

**Main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btErase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Erase"
        android:onClick="eraseClicked"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btDraw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Draw"
        android:onClick="drawClicked"/>

    <aSua.packageName.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawingView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fundo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Com a seguinte Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DrawingView drawingView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        drawingView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawingView);
    }

    public void eraseClicked(View view) {
        drawingView.activateEraser();
    }

    public void drawClicked(View view) {
        drawingView.deactivateEraser();
    }

}
```

---

Não tem a ver com isto mas durante os teste notei que faltava acrescentar `m_Paint.setXfermode(null);` no método `deactivateEraser()`

```
public void deactivateEraser()
{
    m_Paint.setXfermode(null);//<===== Faltava isto
    isEraserActive = false;
}
```

Comment: No caso onde esta o m_Paint.setColor(Color.WHITE) eu mudo ele para m_Paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) ?

Comment: Não. Deixe estar como está.

Comment: Ele esta m_Paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); ai ele não vai apagar, vai pintar de branco por cima

Comment: Falo isso no method touch_start, no primeiro if (caso o usuario esteja apagando)

Comment: Eu testei apenas com as alterações que indiquei na resposta e funciona.

Comment: vou verificar novamente, obrigado.

Comment: Poderia editar a resposta e mostrar como você instanciou a classe DrawingView ? Fiz tudo que esta na sua resposta e não deu certo.

Comment: Acrescentei à resposta a Activity que usei para testes.

Comment: Obrigado @ramaral, funcionou corretamente agora! Em 6 horas envio os pontos.